# How to "Convert" Objective-C IOSByteArray to C uint8_t pointer and vice versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays, uint8t

### Problem:

I have an Objective-C code that uses **[IOSByteArray](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/jre_emul/0.7.2/Classes/IOSByteArray.html)** class for binary data storage/manipulation:

```
IOSByteArray *inputData = ...;
IOSByteArray *outputData = nil;
```

and these data need to be processed in C function:

> int function(const uint8_t * input, size_t inputlen, uint8_t * output,
>   size_t outputlen)

How to correclty pass the **inputData** to the function and get output in IOSByteArray **outputData**?

Comment: Have you tried getBytes:offset:length?

Comment: @Nighthawk441 That looks like it does a copy.

Comment: @Tron looking at the header for IOSByteArray, it looks like char*buffer_ is public, which is the internal storage. https://github.com/shotvibe/minijobjc/blob/master/include/IOSByteArray.h#L31

Comment: @Nighthawk441 The getBytes did not work as expected, however the char*buffer_ is really public and can be used directly. I had to be blind... Thank you very much for your help!